# display mulitple image thumbnails in qt

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

I am trying to list image thumbnails on listwidget . Now I can display a thumbnail . I want to display multiple image thumbnails from a directory.
Here is the code I tried so far.

```
 ui->listWidget->setViewMode(QListWidget::IconMode);
 ui->listWidget->setIconSize(QSize(320,240));
 ui->listWidget->setResizeMode(QListWidget::Adjust);
 ui->listWidget->addItem(new QListWidgetItem(QIcon("image path"),"name"));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use `QDir`, set appropriate filters like `*.png, *.jpg` and in the end use `entryInfoList()` returns a `QFileInfo` list that has the information of the `fileName` and `absoluteFilePath`.

```
ui->listWidget->setViewMode(QListWidget::IconMode);
ui->listWidget->setIconSize(QSize(320,240));
ui->listWidget->setResizeMode(QListWidget::Adjust);

QDir directory("/path/of/directory"); 
directory.setNameFilters({"*.png", "*.jpg"});

for(const QFileInfo & finfo: directory.entryInfoList()){
    QListWidgetItem *item = new QListWidgetItem(QIcon(finfo.absoluteFilePath()), finfo.fileName());
    ui->listWidget->addItem(item);
}
```